# How to parse column separated key-value text with possible multiline strings

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match-all

I need to parse the following text:

```
First: 1
Second: 2
Multiline: blablablabla
bla2bla2bla2
bla3b and key: value in the middle if strting
Fourth: value
```

Value is a string OR multiline string, at the same time value could contain "key: blablabla" substring. Such subsctring should be ignored (not parsed as a separate key-value pair).

Please help me with regex or other algorithm.

Ideal result would be:

```
$regex = "/SOME REGEX/";
$matches = [];
preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches);
// $mathes has all key and value parsed pairs, including multilines values
```

Thank you.

I tried with simple regexes but result is incorrect, because I don't know how to handle multilines:

```
$regex = "/(.+?): (.+?)/";
$regex = "/(.+?):(.+?)\n/";
...
```

Comment: you should have exact pattern to split your sub string. in your scenario you do not have any exact pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~(?<key>[^:\s]+): (?<value>(?>[^\n]*\R)*?[^\n]*)(?=\R\S+:|$)~';

preg_match_all($pattern, $txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: At the 5th line, there's mutiple words before `:` ! => http://regex101.com/r/sR4uA5

Comment: @Enissay: Yes, I know, and that is not what the OP want?

Comment: Oh, probably you're right, I didnt understood/read well the question... But out of curiousity, what would be the solution if that 5th line should've been taken into account ?

Comment: @Enissay: with `key` as key: `(?<key>[^:\s]+):\h(?<value>(?>[^\n]*\R)*?[^\n:]*)(?=\R\S+[ :]|$)`

Comment: @Enissay: in this case replace `\s` with `\v` (vertical white character)

Comment: @Enissay: or better `(?<key>[^:\v]+):\h(?<value>(?>[^\n:]*\R)*[^\n:]*)(?=\R|$)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte with this regex what whould be the solution to hardcode some of the `keys` in regex to make sure they are handled, e.g.

    `(?<key>[^:\v]+|KEY1|KEY WITH SPACE|KEY3):\h(?<value>(?>[^\n:]*\R)*[^\n:]*)(?=\R|$)` - it doesn't work of course :(

Comment: Effectively the same pattern: [`([^:\s]+): ((?>.*\R)*?.*)(?=\R\S+:|$)`](https://3v4l.org/hAZAV)

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of do it, as long as you consider a single word followed by a colon at the start of a line to be a new key start:

```
$data = 'First: 1
Second: 2
Multiline: blablablabla
bla2bla2bla2
bla3b and key: value in the middle if strting
Fourth: value';

preg_match_all('/^([a-z]+): (.*?)(?=(^[a-z]+:|\z))/ims', $data, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

This gives the following result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "First: 1
"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "Second: 2
"
    [2]=>
    string(86) "Multiline: blablablabla
bla2bla2bla2
bla3b and key: value in the middle if strting
"
    [3]=>
    string(13) "Fourth: value"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "First"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Second"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "Multiline"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Fourth"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "1
"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "2
"
    [2]=>
    string(75) "blablablabla
bla2bla2bla2
bla3b and key: value in the middle if strting
"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "value"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Second:"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Multiline:"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "Fourth:"
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```